# Why image layer is not displaying in Google Earth Engine using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine

I am using [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com) notebook. It is similar to jupyter notebook. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/csaybar/EEwPython/blob/master/2_eeImage.ipynb). I used python 3. When I run my code, It only show the folium map. The NDWI layer added to map but the layer image not visualized in map. Please help me to find out the problem. My code is here:

```
# Main function
def Mapdisplay(center, dicc, Tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=10):
  mapViz = folium.Map(location=center, tiles=Tiles, zoom_start=zoom_start, control_scale=True)
  for k, v in dicc.items():
    if ee.image.Image in [type(x) for x in v.values()]:
      folium.TileLayer(
          tiles = EE_TILES.format(**v),
          attr = 'Google Earth Engine',
          overlay = True,
          name = k
      ).add_to(mapViz)
    else:
      folium.GeoJson(
          data = v,
          name = k
      ).add_to(mapViz)
  mapViz.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
  return mapViz

# NDWI calculation
image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20140318')
ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5'])
ndwiMasked = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gte(0.4))
ndwiId = ndwiMasked.getMapId({'min': 0.5, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['00ffff', '0000ff']})

# Function call
Mapdisplay([28.2096,83.9856], {'NDWI masked': ndwiId})
```